# What does the tt metavariable type mean in Rust macros?

Tags: macros, rust, metaprogramming, rust-macros

I'm reading a book about Rust, and start playing with [Rust macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html). All metavariable types are explained there and have examples, except the last one – `tt`. According to the book, it is a “a single token tree”. I'm curious, what is it and what is it used for? Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

That's a notion introduced to ensure that whatever is in a macro invocation correctly matches `()`, `[]` and `{}` pairs. `tt` will match any single token **or** any pair of parenthesis/brackets/braces *with their content*.

For example, for the following program:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

The token trees would be:

- `fn`
- `main`
- `()`

  - ∅
- `{ println!("Hello world!"); }`

  - `println`
  - `!`
  - `("Hello world!")`

    - `"Hello world!"`
  - `;`

Each one forms a tree where simple tokens (`fn`, `main` etc.) are leaves, and anything surrounded by `()`, `[]` or `{}` has a subtree. Note that `(` does not appear alone in the token tree: it's not possible to match `(` without matching the corresponding `)`.

For example:

```
macro_rules! {
    (fn $name:ident $params:tt $body:tt) => { /* … */ }
}
```

would match the above function with `$name → main`, `$params → ()`, `$body → { println!("Hello world!"); }`.

Token tree is the least demanding metavariable type: it matches anything. It's often used in macros which have a “don't really care” part, and especially in macros which have a “head” and a “tail” part. For example, the `println!` macros have a branch matching `($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*)` where `$fmt` is the format string, and `$($arg:tt)*` means “all the rest” and is just forwarded to `format_args!`. Which means that `println!` does not need to know the actual format and do complicated matching with it.

Comment: Why would `println!` not use `expr` instead? Aren't the parameters all expressions?

Comment: @Tomas no, they can also be [named parameters like `foo=expr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#named-parameters) to replace all the `"{foo}"`s.