# Understanding `tt` in Rust's `macro_rules!` macros

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm having trouble understanding what exactly a `tt` is in Rust's `macro_rules!` macros.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303308/1609522), I thought that

> `tt` will match any single token or any pair of parenthesis/brackets/braces with their content.

However, the following example does not seem to follow this rule:

```
macro_rules! foo {
  (content: $content:tt) => {
    mod foo {
      $content
    }
  }
}

foo! (
  content: {
    pub fn main() {
      println!("Hello");
    }  
  }
);
```

I would expect that the `tt` would match everything contained in the `{}` after `content:` and that the result of the macro invocation would be

```
mod foo {
  pub fn main() {
    println!("Hello");
  }
}
```

Instead, I get the following error message:

```
error: expected item, found `{`
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |   content: {
   |            ^ expected item
```

What's going wrong here? Also, why does Rust tell me it's expecting an `item` when I've told it to expect a `tt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tt` is working as expected here. Your macro invocation is as follows:

```rust
foo! (
  content: {
    pub fn main() {
      println!("Hello");
    }  
  }
);
```

`$content` is this:

```rust
{
    pub fn main() {
        println!("Hello");
    }  
}
```

So, the result is this:

```rust
mod foo {
    { // <-- Error occurs here
        pub fn main() {
            println!("Hello");
        }  
    }
}
```

You cannot have another set of curly braces directly inside of a `mod` declaration.

The solution to make your code work is to just put `$content` directly after `mod foo`, but I presume you already saw that:

```
macro_rules! foo {
  (content: $content:tt) => {
    mod foo $content
  }
}

foo! (
  content: {
    pub fn main() {
      println!("Hello");
    }  
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6cf503d0862b30817485d0f5d5bd471).

Comment: Ah, so the `expected item` error is being thrown because I have two sets of curly braces in the post-expansion code, not because I invoked the macro on something that should have been an `item` but wasn't. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! An easy way of telling this is to see where the error is produced. If the token came from the input of the macro, and your resulting code is erroneous, the error still points to the input token, not the macro's implementation.