# Accept struct fields in declarative macro in rust?

Tags: rust, macros

I want to accept struct members in a declarative macro as a simple way of generating enums with common members (I think I have to do it this way because I want to deserialise from a pre-determined JSON format with serde), but it doesn't work:

What I think should work:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($field_1:tt, $field_2:tt) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct Test {
            first: String,
            $field_1,
            $field_2,
        }
    };
}

test!(a: i32, b: i32);
```

The error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: no rules expected the token `:`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:8
   |
1  | macro_rules! test {
   | ----------------- when calling this macro
...
12 | test!(a: i32, b: i32);
   |        ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
   |
note: while trying to match `,`
  --> src/lib.rs:2:17
   |
2  |     ($field_1:tt, $field_2:tt) => {
   |                 ^

error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15e1b1f1939eb4463ebe16c58ee196ec))

Is there any way to do this, or would I have to resort to a proc macro?

Comment: `name : type` is _three_ token trees (`tt`), not one. One way to fix your issue is to spell it out: `($name1:ident : $type1:ty, $name2:ident : $type2:ty)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`TokenTree`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/enum.TokenTree.html) ([`:tt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302026/what-does-the-tt-metavariable-type-mean-in-rust-macros)) is a "single token or a delimited sequence of token trees" You're missing delimiters / aren't matching enough of the token trees (there are three per field definition).

To make this work, you can just match all three token trees that make up the field definition:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($id1:ident : $type1:ty, $id2:ident: $type2:ty) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct Test {
            first: String,
            $id1: $type1,
            $id2: $type2,
        }
    };
}
```

Or for an arbitrary number of field definitions:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ($($id:ident : $type:ty),* $(,)?) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct Test {
            first: String,
            $($id : $type),*
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But is there a way to do this for an arbitrary number of field definitions? I think the fact they have to be within the struct's curly braces would be awkward, though I haven't tried yet

Comment: If you want an arbitrary number of parameters to a macro you'd generally use a repeating capture `$(...),*` for comma delimited. There is no problem using them wherever as long as the result is valid Rust.